# JSON vs. Tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, relational-database

I am trying to make a questionnaire and am considering 2 data structures:

**JSON: I could use JSON to store the different questions as follows:**

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "question": "how old are you?",
            "type": "input_int",
        },
            "question": "what is your name",
            "type": "input_string",
        },
        {
            "question": "how are you today?",
            "type": "multiple_choice",
            "options": [
                "good",
                "bad"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

**Or a table for each type of question:**

```
InputIntTable
- Question
- Order

InputStringTable
- Question
- Order

MultipleChoiceTable
- Question
- Options
- Order
```

I am using Django. Which way would be better both computationally, structurally, and cost wise to host. Which would take more storage? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need to do frequent filtering on question type or any other field of question you can use Json structure. But You cannot query if you save questions as Json. So I think you should use tables. Json should only be used to save data that is just for showing or need to used as dict IMHO. But if you need to query like ORM provides you should use tables

You should have model like:

Question

- question
- order
- type
- options (list of strings, null in case of type "input_int" or "input_string")

No need to create different models for different types, Because then all your questions will be in different tables.

You also cannot use rest views like list, create detail etc. if you save questions as Json.

**In short please use Tables.**

---- EDIT ----

**Question**

- question
- order
- type

**Options**

- options (list of strings)
- question (foreign key to the Question model)

Comment: I see, how come I don't need to use different models for different types? I understand it is bad, but I don't see another way to do it. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I can help you if you need, let me know what you don't understand about doing it in one model.

Comment: I mean, say if I were to expand the number of types of questions, so that I have maybe 100 different types of questions. If I wanted to make a basic string question, there could be like 100 null model fields. Does that take up space? Or is it bad practice?

Comment: yes you are right,  In this case it will take space and its a bad practice. But we can also cater it by creating a new model for options, and only create it whenever we have question of type "multiple_choice". Give me a few minutes I'll update my answer. One more thing, no matter how many types, in current approach you will only have 1 null for one question.

Comment: I see, but then I would have to create a new model for each answer type? Right?

Comment: I think you do not need to specify a type for answer, as your answer will have a foreign key to the question its an answer for (and we can get the type from it). Yes you need to create a new model for Answer, but no need for separate answer model for each type.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but could you update your answer if I were to have a StringQuestion and an IntQuestion?

Comment: Np I understand. I think we do not need to update the Current models, for StringQuestion  we will have "input_string" in type attribute for that question and for IntQuestion we will have "input_int" in type attribute. Can you please tell me what are total types of questions you have right now? It only int, string and multiple above schema will work.

Comment: Well, in the future, it could be much more, such as checkboxes, date field, time field, grid... for example, all of what Google Forms offers.

Comment: interesting, first we need to identify what fields are common in every question, currently common fields are (question, order, type) they are in one model that represent a question in general, if a question needs any extra info like we added for multiple choice question, we can simply add that extra info in separate model and attach it to question just like we did for multiple choice question. But currently the above schema looks like a point to start with.